# How to see functions being called in another program

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, reverse-engineering

I have a windows application written in C/C++ and I would like to be able to see which function is currently being executed in runtime, is that possible with some tool?

Comment: A debugger can do that. But if it is someone elses code and you don't have debug information, then don't expect you will find nice readable names. If you have written the program yourself then do a debug build and run it in the debugger

Comment: Which debugger?

Comment: A debugger suitable for the platform you're running on.

Comment: WinDbg - standalone debugger for MS-Window https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools

Comment: Do you have legal access to the source code (in C or C++) of your application? Did you read books, or followed courses, about C or C++ programming? Are you allowed to recompile that application from its source code, or to change the source code?

Answer (score 3):

The following tools are able to do this

- Debuggers - allow stepping through functions
- Profilers - can show the big picture which functions take longest time to execute
- Some monitoring tools: Process Explorer / Process Hacker can show real-time information on call stack of threads of a process; Process Monitor can track file and registry I/O calls

All those tools rely on debugging symbols. If debugging symbols are not available, they will not be able to show function names (unless for exported/imported functions, or for system functions for which symbols are available through public symbol server)

Note that it may be illegal to reverse-engineer copyrighted software; the software may also take measures against reverse engineering.

Comment: A disasssembler/decompiler cannot "see which function is currently being executed in runtime"

Comment: @fpmurphy, true, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use any IDE like vscode to see the call hierarchy.